# How to create a directory folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, ide, flutter

I'm using Android Studio and I want to create a directory folder inside the lib folder. I right-clicked on the lib folder but the directory option is not showing.
Can anyone suggest to me how to create a directory folder inside a folder?
[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to create package instead of a directory. Seems like Create New Package and Create New Directory will both just create a folder under lib directory.

Comment: Creating  nesting directory with packages looks like package1.pakage2

Answer (score 40):

You need to go **File** -> **Project structure**. 
[image]Select lib folder and unmark as source

Answer (score 32):

Right click on the package then "Mark Directory as" -> Unmark as Sources Root. All child packages will be seen as folders.

[image]

Comment: Does this have unintended side effects? It seems like the lib folder should be the sources root.

Comment: this will disable indexing and so many behind the scenes functions in Android Studio

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution that worked for me In Mac OS,

1- Click over file and select project structure

[image]

2 - After, you should click on the lib folder, then **unselect** the "Source" from top

[image]

3- Then, click on Apply then Ok Buttons

4- Now when you try to create a directory on lib you will found the Directory option appears.

Hopefully, that's what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah I had the same problem, so you just have to follow these steps:

1) Go to project structure
[Here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuRub.png)

2) Go to Modules and find "Sources" tab
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTYbp.png)

3) Uncheck Sources and click "Apply"!
(at the beginning it was unchecked and it didn't work, but when I checked "Sources", my folders changed as it was at the beginning(like packages), so I unchecked again and folders changed, and now I can create directories, not packages, hope it helped you!)

[Like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqv0.png)

Answer (score 5):

This was reported [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2539)

It's an IntelliJ issue in how they deal with folders marked as source. **The lib folder needs to be a source folder for internal flutter purposes.** The best way is to use your file manager or terminal to create the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: There is no pre featured option in Android for adding raw folder unlike Assets folder. Open App folder and select res folder

Step 2: Right click on res folder, select New> Directory, then studio will open a dialog box and it will ask you to enter the name.

Step 3: Write “raw” and click OK. Open res folder and you will find your raw folder under it.

Now you have created raw folder in your project.

Comment: but I want to create inside lib folder. How should I create?

Comment: why does it work only with "raw" and not for another name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built IDE terminal to create the folders.

Comment: "Another option". Okay, what's the original option? your answer is supposed to stand for itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete solution that works. Click the link to see images.
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvjJH.jpg)

Problem- Cannot create Directory
[1)Cannot Create Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKkNB.jpg)

Click the Gear icon and Untick Compact Middle Package
[2)Click Gear icon and Untick Compact Middle Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16p3B.jpg)

Package Structure gets expanded
[3)Now Expanded Package View can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpcuu.jpg)

Still Not possible to create Directory
[4)Still cannot create package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9tBd.jpg)

Do as shown in the image
[5)Right click Package COM->Mark Directory as->Unmark as Source root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdB7H.jpg)

Packages are expanded and now you can create Directory
[6)Now the packages are expanded and now Directory can be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIBND.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For creating the folder in case of flutter framework in Android studio, follow the steps as shown below:-

1. Right click on the folder with the name of your app i.e. the root folder.
2. In the drop down menu click on the new option.
3. After this a drop down menu opens here you will see directory option just click on that.
4. After this enter the name of your directory / folder and press enter this will create a new folder / directory inside your root folder.
5. If you want to make the directory inside the lib folder then just drag the directory from the root folder into the lib folder.
6. After this a dialog box will open in this dialog box check if search for references is tick marked or not if not then tick mark it.
7. Now click ok this will create your directory inside the  lib folder.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Can you simplify your answer in steps so its understood easily.

Comment: Kindly see the above edited answer hope it  may help you solve your problem.